# guint32 date to timestamp in php

Tags: php, date, gtk, timestamp, uint32

I have a date format that is from a GTK\GNOME app that is stored in guint32 date: example: 724605 which I would like to convert into a time-stamp for use with-in a PHP script? Any ideas I have been using Google and trying to come up with a way to convert this?

Comment: here is a link its a dump of the struct of GDate im trying to figure out from the struct with its uint members what the date could be so I can convert it to timestamp. http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html#GDate

Comment: The date being stored is 11/25/1984 if that helps.

Comment: Hi there did you ever find a solution to this? I'm actually trying to do the reverse, take the php time, well actually the js time, and convert to x server time.